# Make Certain Points in Plotly Express Scatterplot different Colors

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, scatter-plot

Currently, I have a scatterplot with each point representing a director, based on the production budget and profit they have. I want to highlight some of these points that standout with their own unique color, and create a legend saying who each one of those points are.
For example,
I want to highlight Joe Russo by making his dot on the graph Green, and then add him to a legend.

Right now, I have the scatterplot that is good. This is my current code:

```
BudProfDirector = px.scatter(BudProfDirectorDF, x = 'production_budget', y = 'Worldwide_Profit', hover_name='primary_name')
```

That gives this graph:
[Plotly Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogmVn.png)

I also have a list of directors I want to highlight:

```
DirectorsToHighlight = ['Pierre Coffin', 'Chris Renaud', 'Kyle Balda','Zack Snyder', 'Christopher Nolan', 'Joe Russo']
```

But have no clue where to go from here

Comment: can you include a sample of your `BudProfDirectorDF`? you can copy and paste the output from `BudProfDirectorDF.head(10).to_dict()` directly into your question. or alternatively, if this data set is free to download online, you can include a link in your question. helping us reproduce your scatterplot will make it easier to provide guidance

Comment: @DerekO making it a dictionary makes it terrible as it's a pandas dataframe, but here is the output of BudProfDirectorDF.head(10):                                            
     primary_name, Worldwide_Profit, production_budget
0 Pierre Coffin 3419745331 294000000
1 Anthony Russo 3182605502 720000000
2 Joe Russo 3182605502 720000000
3 James Wan 2613617575 370000000
4 Joss Whedon 2365349860 555600000
5 Christopher Nolan 2336180484 750000000
6 Michael Bay 2263998250 648000000
7 Chris Renaud 2218783438 300000000
8 Peter Jackson 2172948044 750000000
9 Kyle Balda 2046063923 149000000

Answer (score 1):

To color a specific point and reflect it in the legend, in this case it is easiest to add a graph by creating a new data frame of the same point size at the specific point. The graph is created based on the added data.

```
import plotly.express as px

DirectorsToHighlight = ['Pierre Coffin', 'Chris Renaud', 'Kyle Balda', 'Christopher Nolan', 'Joe Russo']

BudProfDirector = px.scatter(BudProfDirectorDF,
                             x='production_budget',
                             y='Worldwide_Profit',
                             hover_name='primary_name')
df = BudProfDirectorDF[BudProfDirectorDF['primary_name'].isin(DirectorsToHighlight)]

for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row)
    BudProfDirector.add_scatter(x=[row.production_budget],
                                y=[row.Worldwide_Profit],
                                hovertext=[row.primary_name],
                                hovertemplate='<b>%{hovertext}</b><br><br>production_budget=%{x}<br>Worldwide_Profit=%{y}<extra></extra>',
                                name=row.primary_name,
                                mode='markers')

BudProfDirector.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So, when I input this code, I do get the legend, but the dots are not being colored correctly. I think this is because the names are not linked to a variable, but hover_name instead. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: With the data you presented, I understood the points you pointed out by applying my code. I added a graph with only the data extracted by a specific person.